# What can we say about $\int_x^\infty f(t) dt$ for a Schwartz function $f(t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The question is as in the title. What can we say about $F(x):=\int_x^\infty f(t) dt$ for a nonnegative Schwartz function $f(t)$? Here $x$ and $t$ are real-variables.

For example, for the function $f(t)=e^{-t^2}$, $F(x)$ is the error function and integrable on $[c,\infty)$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

For a general nonnegative Schwartz function, does this still hold?

Comment: $\int_c^\infty F(x) dx = \int_c^\infty \int_x^\infty f(t) d t dx \le \int_c^\infty \int_x^\infty  \langle t\rangle ^{-100} dt dx \lesssim \int_c^\infty \langle x\rangle ^{-99} dx < \infty?$

Comment: It seems that the second estimate from the right-hand side seems wrong, if I understand $<,>$ as the Japanese aboslute value symbol.

Comment: Your question is too vague/unclear ... "what can we say" ... I can say that it is written as an integral. I can say that the math symbols used to write it are beautiful, etc. You should edit it if you want better answers ;)

Comment: Why is it wrong?

Comment: Your estimate leads to the conclusion that $F$ is integrable on whole real line, but it is not the case for the error function..